# Finding most similar observations in two data sets

Tags: logistic, similarities

I have the following question.

Given are two data sets A and B with around 10,000 observations described by different variables categorical and numeric. The task is to find these observations in B which are most similar to the observations in A. What approach would you suggest?

My first idea was to build a logistic regression model. Coding all observations with 1 in data set A and all observations with 0 in data set B. The outcome of this approach would be a score. My hypothesis is that the zeros with the highest score are most similar to A. What do you think of this relatively simple approach?

Cheers

Comment: What about a knn classifier? See for instance http://archive2.cra.org/Activities/craw_archive/dmp/awards/2003/Mower/KNN.html

Comment: I' ve read that knn has problems when you work with categorical and numeric variables at the same time?

Comment: Maybe you can find some relevant info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625849/knn-classification-with-categorical-data

Comment: Thank you, so if I would use KNN I have to reclassify every class of every categorical variable into a new variable as a binary variable with 1 and 0?

Comment: Looks like it's a way to do it. Can't help you more on this. Maybe someone else would.

Comment: So you basically have a set of individuals and 2 sets of variables for those individuals, is that right ? If so then Multiple Factor Analysis would be great as it allows to compare the different viewpoints (your two sets of variables)

Answer (score 5):

*This is more of a comment than an answer, but it got too long for the comment box and hopefully it will prompt good discussion.*

Your approach is basically a repurposed version of [propensity score matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propensity_score_matching). The basic technique is general and sound. It's worth noting that Gary King, one of the gurus of logistic regression, objects to propensity score matching for the purposes of causal inference [1], but his objections are specific to causal inference and not to the more general end of inferring similarity.

The Python module Dedupe [2] makes use of similar techniques for matching records. This requires a notion of *equality* between entities in A and B, which might not be applicable to your problem. But the sources they cite in their [bibliography](http://dedupe.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Bibliography.html) could be interesting.

And, as mentioned in [the other answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/208804/36229), using a Random Forest instead of a logistic regression allows you to compute a proximity matrix between points as a side effect [3], [4]. Note that this will also return similarities between points in the *same* data set. This opens up an interesting can of worms: if you compute the similarities among all points in both data sets, you'll naturally have similarities between points in different sets.

#### References

1. King, G. and Nielsen, R. (2016), "Why Propensity Scores Should Not Be Used for Matching." Available at http://j.mp/1FQhySn.
2. Eder, D. and Gregg, F. (2016), *Dedupe*. Available at https://github.com/datamade/dedupe.
3. Liaw, A. and Wiener, M. (2002), Classification and Regression by
   randomForest. R News 2(3), pp. 18-22. Available at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/.
4. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26611881/2954547

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to rate your answer for your answer and for your taste of music ;). Unfortunately I' ve not enough points. But for now it's party time. See you on Monday.

Comment: @burton030 that comment is better than an upvote. CrossValidated is great, welcome